# Python crawler can not successfully sent out form

Tags: python, web-crawler

I am new to Python and trying to crawling the some information on my school website (based on aspx).

What I am trying to do is:

1. http://url.of.the.page
2. Login
3. Open the 4th link on the left

I was trying to log into my account by using `req = urllib2.Request(url,data)` (the `data` contains the id, password and some other information I can see through wireshark) together with `result = opener.open(req)` and `print result.read()`.

Unfortunately the result printed out is the same as the original login page, so I guess I did not login successfully, this result is also same as when I click the 4th lick without login.
(Another proof is that when I wanted to get another link on the web page, I was redirected to the login page).

My question will be:

1. Do I really fail to login?
2. If so what is the correct way to login?

My code is as follow:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import urllib2
import urllib
import cookielib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import datetime
import time
from urlgrabber.keepalive import HTTPHandler

def get_ViewState(soup):      
    view_input = soup.find(id="__VIEWSTATE")      
    return (view_input['value'])  

def get_EventValidation(soup):  
    event_input = soup.find(id="__EVENTVALIDATION")  
    return event_input['value'] 

cookie = cookielib.CookieJar()
keepalive_handler = HTTPHandler()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookie),keepalive_handler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

__url = 'http://url.of.the.page'

opener.addheaders = [('User-agent','Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.104 Safari/537.36')
                    ,('Connection', 'Keep-Alive')
                    ,('Referer',__url)] 


page = urllib.urlopen(__url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

viewstate = get_ViewState(soup)  
eventvalidation = get_EventValidation(soup)

postdata = urllib.urlencode({
        '__EVENTTARGET':'',
        '__EVENTARGUMENT:':'', 
        '__VIEWSTATE':viewstate, 
        'TxtStudentId':'xxxxxxx',    
        'TxtPassword':'xxxxxxx',
        'BtnLogin':'login',
        '__EVENTVALIDATION':eventvalidation
        })




req = urllib2.Request(
        url = __url,    
        data = postdata  
    )

result = opener.open(req)
print result.read()
# result = opener.open(req)
# print result.info()

# print result    
# print result.read() 

print "------------------------------------------------"

#after login, I need to get the scores table
__queryUrl = 'http://url.of.the.page?key=0'
now = datetime.datetime.now()
opener.addheaders = [('Referer', 'http://url.of.the.page?i='+now.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))]

result = opener.open(__queryUrl)
print result.read()

for item in cookie:    
        print 'Cookie：Name = '+item.name    
        print 'Cookie：Value = '+item.value
```

Answer (score 0):

For logging in you will have to use a Programming API for the website because it will probably ask if you are a robot. For clicking the fourth link, simply view the source code (HTML) of the website and find the class and ID of the link you want. Then, with some Googling, you can add that to the code and you are all set :)

Answer (score 0):

By capturing the packages I found out that my POST message get an OK message from the server, that means I did login successfully.

The reason why GET message got a `302 found` as a return is because I didn't include a cookie in the header. I was using urllib2 and it did not include the cookie in the GET message automatically.

So I hard coded the cookie into the header by doing the following:

```
cookie = cookielib.CookieJar()
ckName = ''
ckValue = ''
for item in cookie:    
        ckName = item.name
        ckValue = item.value

opener.addheaders = [('User-agent','Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.104 Safari/537.36')
                    ,('Referer', 'http://202.120.108.14/ecustedu/K_StudentQuery/K_StudentQueryLeft.aspx?i='+now.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
                    ,('Cookie',ckName+'='+ckValue)]
```